# Python: Creating folder structures with inputs and loops

Tags: python, loops, python-3.x, directory

I've probably taken on a bit much as a first Python project, but hey, crash and learn!

I'm trying to find a way to create a folder structure on a network drive, naming the newly created folders on the go, at the moment by typing it in manually. I've nitpicked so far that I've managed to to create the folder structure once, but when it comes to the the third folder level, I'd like it to be possible to create several folders at that level:

- Base folder (Q:)

  - First level (year)

    - Second level (knr)

      - Third level #1 (bgnr)

        - Fourth level #1 (Dumps)
        - Fourth level #2 (Exports)
        - Fourth level #3 (Reports)
      - Third level #2 (bgnr)

        - Fourth level #1 (Dumps)
        - Fourth level #2 (Exports)
        - Fourth level #3 (Reports)

As I stated, I've tried to find my way forward, and this is what I've come up with:

```
    import os, sys, errno
    os.chdir("Q:")
    cwd = os.getcwd()
    year = input("What year?: ")
    if not os.path.exists(year):
        os.makedirs(year)
    os.chdir(year)
    knr = input("Write K-number: ")
    if not os.path.exists(knr):
        os.makedirs(knr)
    os.chdir(knr)
    bgnr = input("Write BG-nummer: ")
    if not os.path.exists(bgnr):
        os.makedirs(bgnr)
    os.chdir(bgnr)
    os.makedirs("Dumps")
    os.makedirs("Exports")
    os.makedirs("Reports")
```

I tried with the following, but failed miserably..

```
    def bgnrloop():
        global retake
        retake = input("Do you want to create another folder? (Y/N) ")

        if retake() in {"y", "Y"}:
            bgnrfunc()
        elif retake() in {"n", "N"}:
            bgnrfunc()
        else:
            print("Valid response: y/Y or n/N.")
    bgnrloop()
```

Sorry about indentation etc, it doesn't pose the problem at hand right away I think.. Just trying to get the "loopback" to work. And yes, I know it is a mess.

Answer (score 0):

Go back to your level two directory:

```
os.chdir('Q:\\year\\knr\\')
```

Or if on Linux/Mac:

```
os.chdir('Q:/year/knr/')
```

Comment: I've managed to get the folder creation sorted like I want to, it's the possibility to create another folder right away after  the whole structure is by answering yes, or no to stop

Comment: To clarify, it's from `bgnr = input("Write BG-nummer: ")` and down to `os.makedirs("Reports")` that I want to make loopable..

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution! Still got some touching up to do, but I've managed to get it to work in IDLE and PyScripter.

```
#! python 3.3.3

import os, sys, errno
os.chdir("Q:")
year = input("What year?: ")
if not os.path.exists(year):
    os.makedirs(year)
os.chdir(year)
knr = input("Write K-number: ")
if not os.path.exists(knr):
    os.makedirs(knr)
os.chdir(knr)
bgnr = input("Write BG-nummer: ")
    if not os.path.exists(bgnr):
        os.makedirs(bgnr)
        os.chdir(bgnr)
        os.makedirs("Dumps")
        os.makedirs("Exports")
        os.makedirs("Reports")
bgnrcreate()

while True:
        answer = input("Skapa mer? (j/n): ")
        if answer == "n":
                break
        else:
            os.chdir(os.pardir)
            bgnrcreate()
sys.exit(0)
```